# Scrolling to the bottom of a ScrollView on initial load

Tags: react-native

I have a large long image with a few inputs at the bottom in my react native view. When the view loads I want it to be "scrolled" to the bottom of the page -- all the examples I can find online are triggered because of some event that the user does.

I want to call scrollToEnd() but I'm not sure where in the lifecycle the ref will actually be set -- anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `scrollToEnd` this way. It will take to the bottom of `ScrollView`

```
   <ScrollView
    ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{        
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
    }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with your question but

With react-native Image component we have onLoad prop. I think this is what you are looking for.
try something like:

```
<Image source={{uri...}} onLoad={(e)=>this.handleImageLoaded(e)}/>
```

then inside handleImageLoaded method you can use scrollToEnd() with some ref as per your code.

also there are other useful props like onLoadStart/End check here

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Or if you are just waiting for the view to render then to scroll
for that I think componentDidAppear() lifecycle method, if using react-native -navigation by wix

or with react-navigation
willFocus, willBlur, didFocus and didBlur events for the component render cycle.. explained here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle